# XWPFTableCell remove bodyElement (Table)

Tags: java, apache-poi, cell, xwpf

I try create report with `org.apache.poi`. I've created template with table where I wanted to copy row and insert info. The one cell contains two paragraphs and the small table between them.

So, I want remove the table sometimes, but `XWPFTableCell` don't have the required method. Only `removeParagraph(int p1)`.

How to remove the table inside the cell?

It's code of clone method of cell

```
public static void cloneCell(XWPFTableCell clone, XWPFTableCell source) {
    CTTcPr cttcPr = clone.getCTTc().isSetTcPr() ? clone.getCTTc().getTcPr() : clone.getCTTc().addNewTcPr();
    cttcPr.set(source.getCTTc().getTcPr());

    int indexParag = 0, indexTable = 0;
    for (IBodyElement iBodyElement : source.getBodyElements()) {
        BodyElementType beType = iBodyElement.getElementType();
        if (beType == BodyElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
            XWPFParagraph sourceParag = (XWPFParagraph)iBodyElement;
            XWPFParagraph cloneParag = indexParag < clone.getParagraphs().size() ? clone.getParagraphs().get(indexParag) : clone.addParagraph();
            cloneParagraph(cloneParag, sourceParag);
            indexParag++;
        } else if (beType == BodyElementType.TABLE) {
            XWPFTable sourceTable = (XWPFTable)iBodyElement;
            XWPFTable cloneTable = indexTable < clone.getTables().size() ? clone.getTables().get(indexTable) : clone.insertNewTbl(sourceTable.getCTTbl().newCursor());
            if (cloneTable == null)
                cloneTable = new XWPFTable(clone.getCTTc().addNewTbl(), clone);

            cloneTable(cloneTable, sourceTable);
            indexTable++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your cell you have a `XWPFTable` ?

Comment: Yes. I copy rows and I copy content of cell as IBodyElement. It paragraphs and tables.

Answer (score 1):

I use code like this. There are two really bad methods which access fields of the cell directly. I cannot find a correct way to access body elements list and tables list.

The method removes elements from parent (document body element or cell element) starting from the startIndex and count shows how many elements to be removed.

NOTE: The last element in the table must be a paragraph so don't remove the last paragraph element. Make it empty (remove the runs instead).

```
public void removeElements(IBody parent, int startIndex, int count) {
    if (parent instanceof XWPFTableCell) {
        XWPFTableCell cell = (XWPFTableCell)parent;
        List<IBodyElement> bodyElementsRef = getBodyElementsRef(cell);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            IBodyElement element = bodyElementsRef.get(startIndex);
            if (element instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
                int realParIndex = getParagraphIndex(bodyElementsRef, (XWPFParagraph)element);
                cell.getParagraphs().remove(realParIndex);
                cell.getCTTc().removeP(realParIndex);
            } else if (element instanceof XWPFTable) {
                int realTableIndex = getTableIndex(bodyElementsRef, (XWPFTable) element);
                getTablesRef(cell).remove(realTableIndex);
                cell.getCTTc().removeTbl(realTableIndex);
            }
            bodyElementsRef.remove(startIndex);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            parent.getXWPFDocument().removeBodyElement(startIndex);
        }
    }
}

private int getParagraphIndex(List<IBodyElement> bodyElementsRef, XWPFParagraph paragraph) {
    int index = -1;
    for(IBodyElement elem : bodyElementsRef) {
        if (elem instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
            index++;
        }
        if (elem == paragraph) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private int getTableIndex(List<IBodyElement> bodyElementsRef, XWPFTable table) {
    int index = -1;
    for(IBodyElement elem : bodyElementsRef) {
        if (elem instanceof XWPFTable) {
            index++;
        }
        if (elem == table) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 * It's a dirty hack but I cannot find proper way to remove elements from cell's body elements
 * @param cell
 * @return
 */
private List<IBodyElement> getBodyElementsRef(XWPFTableCell cell) {
    try {
        Field beField = cell.getClass().getDeclaredField("bodyElements");
        beField.setAccessible(true);
        return (List<IBodyElement>) beField.get(cell);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
/**
 * It's a dirty hack but I cannot find proper way to remove elements from cell's tables list
 * @param cell
 * @return
 */
private List<XWPFTable> getTablesRef(XWPFTableCell cell) {
    try {
        Field beField = cell.getClass().getDeclaredField("tables");
        beField.setAccessible(true);
        return (List<XWPFTable>) beField.get(cell);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```